# ¿Cómo puedo usar las cadenas f?

Tags: python

```
num1 = int(input("Dime un número"))
num2 = int(input("Dime otro número"))
print("La suma de ", num1 ," y ", num2 ," es ", num1+num2 )
```

Como podéis ver en el código, se sumarían dos números que se pedirían anteriormente.

Mi duda es,¿por qué no puedo escribir lo siguiente si estoy usando VS code con Python 3.8?
He probado a reinstalar mi versión de python,probar otras y nada.
`print(f"La suma de {num1} y {num2} es {num1+num2}")`

Comment: Obtienes algún error?

Comment: Hola, la sintaxis es correcta, ¿te da alguna excepción en concreto? Ese código es totalmente válido para Python >= 3.6, a no ser que VSCode esté ejecutando una versión anterior si tienes más intérpretes instalados en el equipo ... Antes de esa línea (la del f-string) pon ésta: `import sys;print(sys.version)` y muestra que te imprime.

Comment: @FJSevilla  ahora sí me sale, muchas gracias.
Lo que ocurre es que me sigue extrañando porque la f en print(f"") no se colorea de azul,además de los elementos {} que tampoco se colorean.
También me sale 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] lo cual no sé lo que es.

Comment: Que se coloree o no no es cosa de Pyhon eso solo depende de tu IDE o editor de texto y el sistema de resaltado de sintaxis que use. No recuerdo si VSCode lo hacía, por ejemplo se que PyCharm y Eric por ejemplo si, Spyder no. La salida que muestras es la cadena sys.version, muestra la versión de Python, compilador, fecha de compilación, etc, era solo para confirmar que usas una versión con f-strings.